# How to perform map function on an element of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple function that I am looking to simplify further:

```js
setAreas() {
  this.areas = ipcRenderer.sendSync('request', 'areas').map(_area => {
    _area.locations = _area.locations.map(locationId => this.getLocation(locationId))
    return _area
  })
}
```

Is there any way to reduce this to a one-liner by performing the map on `_area.locations` and returning the updated `_area`?

Comment: I guess 'readable one-liner' is what I meant. I just feel like there is a built-in JavaScript function to do what I'm trying to accomplish and I can't find it

Comment: I will be better if you include some sample of input and expected output to helps us understand what you are doing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use `Object.assign`, which will return the base object being assigned to:

```
setAreas() {
  this.areas = ipcRenderer.sendSync('request', 'areas').map(_area => (
    Object.assign(_area, { locations: _area.locations.map(locationId => this.getLocation(locationId)) })
  ));
}
```

But that's not so readable. I prefer your current code.

Note that `.map` is appropriate for when you're transfoming one array into another. Here, you're only *mutating* every object in an existing array; `forEach` is more appropriate:

```
setAreas() {
  this.areas = ipcRenderer.sendSync('request', 'areas');
  this.areas.forEach((a) => a.locations = a.locations.map(locationId => this.getLocation(locationId)))
}
```

If `getLocation` only accepts one parameter, you can golf

```
a.locations = a.locations.map(locationId => this.getLocation(locationId))
```

down to

```
a.locations = a.locations.map(this.getLocation.bind(this))
```

(you could even remove the `.bind(this)` if `this` context isn't needed)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I updated my code to reflect your solution. It was a pretty silly question, but I'm glad I learned a bit about when to use forEach vs map. The logic you used makes much more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
setAreas() {
  this.areas = ipcRenderer.sendSync('request', 'areas').map(_area => ({
    ..._area, locations: _area.location.map(locationId => this.getLocation(locationId))
  })
}
```